# Are there email clients on the Mac that only download recent emails?

Tags: macos, email, software-recommendation

I have tried a number of clients every now and then over the past 5, 6 years, *Apple Mail, MS Outlook, Inky, Sparrow, Unibox, Mozilla Thunderbird*, etc. Thunderbird had a function whose description is the most similar - you can set synchronisation to days weeks or months but it didn't work or maybe I misunderstood that function. Are there email clients that can behave kinda like the mail apps on iOS/ Android, so they only download a fixed amount of recent emails?

I want my client to handle my emails **syncing (perhaps caching is a better word) only the recent, say, 30 days of emails**, if possible, allowing the parsing/ searching of older emails on demand (pretty much exactly like the mobile phone apps).**

Advantages:

- This will keep the database small;
- prevent unnecessary redownloading of confidential company files since I expect to do this on my future primary laptops too;
- and also prevent potential syncing problems by first going through my entire mailbox.